# How can a python configuration files' (INI file) key's value be appended by number in increasing order?

Tags: python, nested-lists, configuration-files, ini

I want to assign each lists value to a Key which is appended by number in the increasing order till the size of the list.

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3],[7,4],[1]]
```

Example output of INI configuration file :

```
[List1]
Signal1 = 1
Signal2 = 2
Signal3 = 3

[List2]
Signal1 = 7
Signal2 = 4

[List3]
Signal1 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The straitforward way:

```
def ll_to_string(ll):
    s = ''
    for li, l in enumerate(ll):
        s += f'[List{li + 1}]\n'
        for i, n in enumerate(l):
            s += f'Signal{i + 1} = {n}\n'
        s += '\n'
    return s


def write_all(all, file_name):
    with open(file_name, "w", encoding='utf-8') as fw:
        fw.write(all)


list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [7, 4], [1]]
all = ll_to_string(list_of_lists)
# print(all)
write_all(all, 'out.txt')
```

If you want use `configparser.py` module:

```
def config_ll_to_ini(ll, file_name):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    for li, l in enumerate(ll):
        d = {}
        for i, n in enumerate(l):
            d[f'Signal{i + 1}'] = n
        config[f'List{li + 1}'] = d
    with open(file_name, 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)


# usage
config_ll_to_ini(list_of_lists, 'cfg.ini')
```

And think twice before you decide use **INI** format, nowdays most applications use **json**, **xml**, **yaml** etc, and **INI** seems outdated.

Comment: Hi Lei thankyou for the answer it works perfectly for .txt file. But I was looking to write it in a .ini file using the configparser.py lib in python so it is can also be easily read back.